# The enum HashAlgorithmType in .Net standard 2.0 is missing Sha256, Sha384 and Sha512

Tags: .net-standard-2.0

I have a project in .Net Framework 4.7.1 that I want to upgrade to .Net standard. I just created a new project and copied all my code there. In a class, I make use of the HashAlgorithmType enum. In .Net Standard this enum had values None, Md5, Sha1, Sha256, Sha384 and Sha512. However, in the .Net standard project the three last are missing from the library.

I have checked the documentation, and all six values should be there in both cases.

The decompiler shows this in the .Net Framework project:

```
namespace System.Security.Authentication
{
  /// <summary>Specifies the algorithm used for generating message authentication codes (MACs).</summary>
  [__DynamicallyInvokable]
  public enum HashAlgorithmType
  {
    /// <summary>No hashing algorithm is used.</summary>
    [__DynamicallyInvokable] None = 0,
    /// <summary>The Message Digest 5 (MD5) hashing algorithm.</summary>
    [__DynamicallyInvokable] Md5 = 32771, // 0x00008003
    /// <summary>The Secure Hashing Algorithm (SHA1).</summary>
    [__DynamicallyInvokable] Sha1 = 32772, // 0x00008004
    /// <summary>The Secure Hashing Algorithm 2 (SHA-2), using a 256-bit digest.</summary>
    Sha256 = 32780, // 0x0000800C
    /// <summary>The Secure Hashing Algorithm 2 (SHA-2), using a 384-bit digest.</summary>
    Sha384 = 32781, // 0x0000800D
    /// <summary>The Secure Hashing Algorithm 2 (SHA-2), using a 512-bit digest.</summary>
    Sha512 = 32782, // 0x0000800E
  }
}
```

But in the .Net standard project, the decompiler shows this:

```
namespace System.Security.Authentication
{
  /// <summary>Specifies the algorithm used for generating message authentication codes (MACs).</summary>
  public enum HashAlgorithmType
  {
    /// <summary>No hashing algorithm is used.</summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    None = 0,
    /// <summary>The Message Digest 5 (MD5) hashing algorithm.</summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    Md5 = 32771, // 0x00008003
    /// <summary>The Secure Hashing Algorithm (SHA1).</summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    Sha1 = 32772, // 0x00008004
  }
}
```

Comment: That's the fact: https://learn.microsoft.com/hu-hu/dotnet/api/system.security.authentication.hashalgorithmtype?view=netstandard-2.0

Comment: Ok, I wasn't looking correctly at the documentation. I do not understand why in .net standard there are less items...

Comment: Simple answer: they were was not part of that standard level, but they are there in 2.1: https://learn.microsoft.com/hu-hu/dotnet/api/system.security.authentication.hashalgorithmtype?view=netstandard-2.1